# glm.fit: algorithm did not converge – Propensity Score matching doesn't work?

Tags: r, logistic, propensity-scores, matching

I am doing a Propensity Score Matching (nearest neighbor matching) in R.

I am matching patients with different treatments. Depending on the diagnosis I matched different subsamples. In some of the subsamples the code works and I could reduce the distance (SMD), but in two of the subsamples it didn't work and I always get the warning message `glm.fit: algorithm did not converge`. When I look at the distance after the matching, it hasn't changed. The following is my code:

```
data.combined_1 = data.combined %>% 
  filter(diag.kat=="Psychotrope Substanzen (10-19)")

mat=matchit(
  formula = th_wechsel ~  oq30_gesamt + sex 
    + anz.sitzung + alter + BSI_Gesamt 
    + familienstand + arbeitsunfähigkeit, 
  data = data.combined_1, 
  method = "nearest",
  distance = "logit",
  ratio = 1)
```

I really don't know, what the problem is and am grateful for any piece of advice.

Comment: It may be that in those subsamples th_wechsel is always zero or one for some combination of the predictors (assuming th_wechsel is a binary variable). I would check that first. If that does not answer then you need to give us more details about the dataset.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I have two samples, one with change in therapist (th_wechsel =1) and one with no change in therapist (th_wechsel =0) and I always match a patient with transfer with a patient without a transfer while also considering their diagnosis through subsamples. In the subsamples there are always enough control patients to be matched with the transfer patients, so I don't think that is the reason. What kind of detail you need about the dataset?

Comment: This has nothing to do with matching and is all about fitting a `glm()` model for the propensity score. Try running `glm(th_wechsel ~ oq30_gesamt+sex+anz.sitzung+alter+BSI_Gesamt+familienstand+arbeitsunfähigkeit, data = data.combined_1, family = binomial)` and investigate the results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The `matchit` algorithm is performing logistic regression under the hood. The warning is telling you that the logistic regression model cannot be estimated due to perfect prediction, or singularity of the odds ratio.

According to the formula, `th_wechsel` is the exposure of interest and age, sex, etc. are the possible confounders. Not knowing the sample size, nor the coding of these variables, you are probably dealing with too high a dimension to guarantee that the model can even be fit at all. In other words, there is a lack of an adequate propensity matched set for all levels of the exposure of interest.

You can experiment with changing the model, usually categorical variables with sparse counts can be tricky, and practically a simpler model can be had be collapsing categories. For instance, if age is coded categorically by year, maybe coarsen it to age in 5 year increments.